# Web accessibility and h1-h6 headings - must all content be under these tags?

Tags: web, accessibility, w3c, wcag

At the top of many pages in our web application we have error messages and notifications, 'Save' and other buttons, and **then** our h1 tag with the content title. When making a web application accessible, is it ever acceptable to have content above the top-level structure tag like we do here?

Answer (score 5):

As a screen reader user I don't like content above the main heading. Normally I navigate by headings so would miss the error message. A better solution is to output an h1 heading above the error message, then leave the rest of your headings in tact giving you two h1 headings.

Answer (score 2):

Yes (you can put stuff above them). The H simply means Heading. It's a question of what the heading relates to I guess.

My only caveat is, H2 shouldn't really be above H1, and H3 Shouldn't be above H2. But I don't think it's an actual rule.Websites have menus, warning, notifications. It's acceptable to put them above the rest of your content. I don't see how it would affect accessibility as long as your content is ordered logically. Look at the page CSS turned off. Does it look logical? That's the most important part of accessibility.

Although some people do go that extra mile and have the menu as the last item in the markup and use CSS to bring it back to the top. Personally, I find that solution counter productive. The menu is still important, it belongs at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just consider it is in that order that the user will get the information. So, if you just did an operation it sounds like a good idea to get any message related to it as the first thing. If it is a notification that appears on any page unrelated to what you are doing, I wouldn't put it above, as it might be a little weird. 
Also you can use a text browser that doesn't use styles, it should look like a document with appropriate headers.

Answer (score 0):

Heading tags are used to indicate the hierarchy of the content below it. You should only have one h1 tag and it should be the first content to appear on your page (this is usually the name of the site). Also, you shouldn't skip heading tags when drilling down through different tiers of content.

In your case, you can still use CSS to position items above the h1 tag as long as it is in the correct order in the html.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the elements above the heading are used by JavaScript. In that case, it's preferable if they are created by JavaScript, not included in the source of the page.

To return to your original question, it is probably best that they be at the foot of the page. However, if they are hidden using the CSS "display: none;" or "visibility: hidden;" properties then they will not be seen by most (perhaps all?) screenreaders or by many other assistive technologies, and so should not be an issue. I've written a fairly detailed [explanation of why accessibility technology ignores such elements](http://www.nickfitz.co.uk/2007/02/14/why-left-9999px-is-better-for-accessibility-than-display-none/).

Of course if somebody disables CSS things are going to look pretty messy. If there is content on the page that can be used even when CSS and/or JavaScript are disabled, then putting those elements at the bottom of the page will at least make things less cluttered.